# How to Sum all the column values in table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my web application, I'm dynamically adding table rows to the table using javascript.

There is a Qty Col, Unit Amount Col, and Line Total Col in each row.

After adding a record to the table user also can remove the line.

In this scenario, I want to get the total of **Line Total** col values to show as the **Total Value**

How can I calculate that using javascript?

Here is my current code.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
  <table class="table table-striped" id="submissionTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>MEASURE BY</th>
        <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
        <th>LINE TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
      <tr id="tablerow0"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>
    <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

This is how dynamically add rows to the table.

```
var counter = 1;

var dropdownOptions = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Item_ID));

$(function () {
  $("#add").click(function () {
    var newRow = $(
       '<tr id="tablerow' +
       counter +
       '" class ="poSet"> ' +
       "<td>" +
       '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
       counter +
       "</strong></label>" +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="40%">' +
       '<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select ItemId" data-id= ' + counter + ' name="Item_Id[' +
       counter +
       ']" id="ItemId[' + counter + ']" required="required" ' +
       "</select>" +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="10%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control Qty" name="Qty[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="1" id="Qty[' + counter + ']" onchange="calQtyBase(this)" data-QtyId= ' + counter + ' required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="10%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MeasureBy[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="" id="MeasureBy[' + counter + ']" readonly />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="20%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control UnitPrice" name="Unit_Price[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="0.00" id="UnitPrice[' + counter + ']"  onchange="priceBase(this)" data-PriceId= ' + counter + '  required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       '<td width="20%">' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control LineTotal" name="Line_Total[' +
       counter +
       ']" value="0.00" id="LineTotal[' + counter + ']"    required="required" />' +
       "</td>" +
       "<td>" +
       '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
       counter +
       ');">x</button>' +
       "</td>" +
       "</tr>"
     );
    
    var selectElement = newRow.find("select"); 

    dropdownOptions.forEach(function (option) {
      var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
      selectElement.append(optionElement);
    });

    newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");

    selectElement.select2();

    counter++;
    return false;
  });
});
```

Here I wrote a 2 javascript to calculate the line total when the **Qty** or **Unit Price** is changed in the event of **OnChange**

```
 function calQtyBase(e) {

   var dataId = e.getAttribute("data-QtyId");
   var Qty = document.getElementById('Qty[' + dataId + ']').value;
   var UnitAmount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('UnitPrice[' + dataId + ']').value);
   var total = Qty * UnitAmount;
   document.getElementById('LineTotal[' + dataId + ']').value = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

 }
```

```
 function priceBase(e) {
   var dataId = e.getAttribute("data-PriceId");
   var Qty = document.getElementById('Qty[' + dataId + ']').value;
   var UnitAmount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('UnitPrice[' + dataId + ']').value);
   var total = Qty * UnitAmount;
   document.getElementById('LineTotal[' + dataId + ']').value = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var counter = 1;

var dropdownOptions = [{
  "Value": "test",
  "Text": "tyty"
}];

$(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var newRow = $(
      '<tr id="tablerow' +
      counter +
      '" class ="poSet"> ' +
      "<td>" +
      '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
      counter +
      "</strong></label>" +
      "</td>" +
      '<td width="40%">' +
      '<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select ItemId" data-id= ' + counter + ' name="Item_Id[' +
      counter +
      ']" id="ItemId[' + counter + ']" required="required" ' +
      "</select>" +
      "</td>" +
      '<td width="10%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control Qty" name="Qty[' +
      counter +
      ']" value="1" id="Qty[' + counter + ']" data-QtyId= ' + counter + ' required="required" />' +
      "</td>" +
      '<td width="10%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MeasureBy[' +
      counter +
      ']" value="" id="MeasureBy[' + counter + ']" readonly />' +
      "</td>" +
      '<td width="20%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control UnitPrice" name="Unit_Price[' +
      counter +
      ']" value="0.00" id="UnitPrice[' + counter + ']"  data-PriceId= ' + counter + '  required="required" />' +
      "</td>" +
      '<td width="20%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control LineTotal" name="Line_Total[' +
      counter +
      ']" value="0.00" id="LineTotal[' + counter + ']"    required="required" />' +
      "</td>" +
      "<td>" +
      '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
      counter +
      ');">x</button>' +
      "</td>" +
      "</tr>"
    );

    var selectElement = newRow.find("select");

    dropdownOptions.forEach(function(option) {
      var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
      selectElement.append(optionElement);
    });

    newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");

    selectElement.select2();

    counter++;
    return false;
  });
});

//onchange of qty & unitprice
$(document).on("change", ".Qty , .UnitPrice ", function() {
  var element = $(this).closest("tr");
  var qty = element.find(".Qty").val();
  var unit_price = element.find(".UnitPrice").val();
  var total = qty * unit_price;
  element.find(".LineTotal").val(parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));

  calculate_total(); //call function

})


function calculate_total() {
  var sum = 0;
  //looping
  $('[id*=LineTotal]').each(function(el) {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val()) // adding values
  })
  $("#total").text(sum.toFixed(2)) //added in total div..

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
  <table class="table table-striped" id="submissionTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>MEASURE BY</th>
        <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
        <th>LINE TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
      <tr id="tablerow0"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  Total :
  <div id="total"></div>
  <p>
    <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through your `lineTotal` input box and add the value of each input on each iteration using `+=` and then assign this value to any div for showing total.

Also, i have done little changes in your current code so instead of multiple functions added change handler which will get call for both qty & price change and inside that handler `calculate_total` function gets called to update the total.

***Demo Code :***

```js
var counter = 1;

var dropdownOptions = [{
  "Value": "test",
  "Text": "tyty"
}];

$(function() {
  $("#add").click(function() {
    var newRow = $(
      '<tr id="tablerow' +
      counter +
      '" class ="poSet"> ' +
      "<td>" +
      '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
      counter +
      "</strong></label>" +
      "</td>" +
      '<td width="40%">' +
      '<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select ItemId" data-id= ' + counter + ' name="Item_Id[' +
      counter +
      ']" id="ItemId[' + counter + ']" required="required" ' +
      "</select>" +
      "</td>" +
      '<td width="10%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control Qty" name="Qty[' +
      counter +
      ']" value="1" id="Qty[' + counter + ']" data-QtyId= ' + counter + ' required="required" />' +
      "</td>" +
      '<td width="10%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="MeasureBy[' +
      counter +
      ']" value="" id="MeasureBy[' + counter + ']" readonly />' +
      "</td>" +
      '<td width="20%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control UnitPrice" name="Unit_Price[' +
      counter +
      ']" value="0.00" id="UnitPrice[' + counter + ']"  data-PriceId= ' + counter + '  required="required" />' +
      "</td>" +
      '<td width="20%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control LineTotal" name="Line_Total[' +
      counter +
      ']" value="0.00" id="LineTotal[' + counter + ']"    required="required" />' +
      "</td>" +
      "<td>" +
      '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
      counter +
      ');">x</button>' +
      "</td>" +
      "</tr>"
    );

    var selectElement = newRow.find("select");

    dropdownOptions.forEach(function(option) {
      var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.Value).text(option.Text);
      selectElement.append(optionElement);
    });

    newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");

    selectElement.select2();

    counter++;
    return false;
  });
});

//onchange of qty & unitprice
$(document).on("change", ".Qty , .UnitPrice ", function() {
  var element = $(this).closest("tr");
  var qty = element.find(".Qty").val();
  var unit_price = element.find(".UnitPrice").val();
  var total = qty * unit_price;
  element.find(".LineTotal").val(parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));

  calculate_total(); //call function

})


function calculate_total() {
  var sum = 0;
  //looping
  $('[id*=LineTotal]').each(function(el) {
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val()) // adding values
  })
  $("#total").text(sum.toFixed(2)) //added in total div..

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive text-nowrap">
  <table class="table table-striped" id="submissionTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>MEASURE BY</th>
        <th>UNIT PRICE</th>
        <th>LINE TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
      <tr id="tablerow0"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  Total :
  <div id="total"></div>
  <p>
    <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can easily write a function that adds all the columns of a row:

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Sample</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hammer</td>
                    <td>101</td>
                    <td>9.99</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Screwdriver</td>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>4.99</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <button onclick="sumQuantity()">Sum Quantity</button>
        <button onclick="sumPrice()">Sum Price</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now you can add a table helper class that uses `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` to get the columns and rows (via `tr` and `td`) for the table:

```js
class TableUtils {
    #table
    #head
    #body

    constructor(selector) {
        this.#table = document.querySelector(selector)
        this.#head = this.#table.querySelector('thead')
        this.#body = this.#table.querySelector('tbody')
    }

    getCell(row, column) {
        const rows = this.#body.querySelectorAll('tr')
        const selectedRow = rows[row]
        const cells = selectedRow.querySelectorAll('td')
        return cells[column]
    }

    getColumnByHeader(header) {
        const headers = this.#head.querySelectorAll('th')
        const index = Array.from(headers).findIndex(th => th.textContent === header)
        const rows = this.#body.querySelectorAll('tr')
        return Array.from(rows).map(row => row.querySelectorAll('td')[index])
    }

    sum(column) {
        if (typeof column === 'number') {
            let sum = 0
            for (let i = 0; i < this.rowCount; i++) {
                const cell = this.getCell(i, column)
                const value = parseFloat(cell.textContent)
                if (isNaN(value)) {
                    continue
                }
                sum += value
            }
            return sum
        } else if (typeof column === 'string') {
            const cells = this.getColumnByHeader(column)
            let sum = 0
            for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                const value = parseFloat(cells[i].textContent)
                if (isNaN(value)) {
                    continue
                }
                sum += value
            }
            return sum
        }
    }

    get rowCount() {
        return this.#body.querySelectorAll('tr').length
    }

    get columnCount() {
        return this.#head.querySelectorAll('th').length
    }
}
```

Next you will want to add the functions to sum the quantity and price rows:

```js
function sumQuantity() {
    const table = new TableUtils('table')
    const sum = table.sum('Quantity')
    alert(sum)
}

function sumPrice() {
    const table = new TableUtils('table')
    const sum = table.sum(2)
    alert(sum)
}
```

`sumQuantity` uses the table header "Quantity" to evaluate its sum, while `sumPrice` uses the column index to sum the entire column.

~ Hope this helps